# Add custom field in tier price in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have modified Magento tierprice set and customized the file:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/catalog/product/edit/price/tier.phtml
```

Data from two new fields (`"cost", "setupcost"`) is successfully showing in the tier page.

How do I insert the data into table `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`? 
 I want to save this data when product page save button clicked.